# WP8 Clear navigation history on WebBrowser control

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, webbrowser-control

I am developing an app in Windows Phone 8, and I have a XAML page with a WebBrowser control to load some sites. When I load a new site, I need to delete the browsing history so far.  How can I do that with c#?

```
myBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
...
myBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.yahoo.com"));
myBrowser.ClearCookiesAsync();
myBrowser.ClearInternetCacheAsync();
myBrowser.CanGoBack();  //returns true
```

Regards

Comment: What is the reason for deleting the history?

Comment: I want to keep the history only from the site selected, omitting the history from the previous site.  So, if the user go back, can only navigate until the site selected